# C File pointer returns the contents of a file twice

Tags: c

With the following program, I wish to read a file (say, a text file) and store all of it's contents in a variable. So, to achieve it, I cooked up the following with the help of Stack Overflow suggestions. However, this program returns the contents of a file twice. 
For instance, let the following program read a text file with the following contents:

- John Start 0
- Using *,15

Then, the program will display the following:

- John Start 0
- Using *,15
- John Start 0
- Using *,15

Thus, I would like your help in finding out the problem. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
    //Program to read a file and store it's contents in a single variable
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    /*Reads contents of a file and returns address of variable, in which file contents are stored*/
    char* fileRead(char*);
    //Concatenates 2 strings
    char* concat(char*,char*);  
    //Calculates the size of the file
    unsigned long fsize(char* file);

    int main()
    {

      char *prt, *out;
      //Allocate memory & take the input of the file name to read
      prt = malloc(256);
      printf("\nEnter the name of the file : \t");
      scanf("%255s",prt);
      //Copy the address of read data & output it
      out = fileRead(prt);
      printf("\nContents : \n-----------------\n%s", out);

      free(out);    
      free(prt);
      return 0;
    }

    char* fileRead(char *file)
    {   
      //function to read the contents of a file

      FILE  *fip;
      char *text, *temp, read[1024];
      int size, i=0;

      fip=fopen(file, "r");
      size=(int)fsize(file);

      temp = malloc(size*10);
      text = temp;
      //If the file doesn't exist then...
      if(fip==NULL)
      {
        temp = strdup("ERROR : File doesn't exist! Please try again!\n");
        return temp;
      } 
      //Begin concatenation, once after the file reading has been initiated
      while(fgets(read, 1024, fip) != NULL)
      {
        temp = concat(text,read);i++;
      }

      fclose(fip);

      return text;
     }

     char* concat(char* dest, char* src)
     {  
      //function to concatenate src to dest
      while(*dest) dest++;  
      while(*dest++ = *src++);
      return --dest;
     }

     unsigned long fsize(char* file)
     {  
      //calculates the size of file
      FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
      fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
      unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
      fclose(f);
      return len;
     }
```

Edit 1: Thanks a lot people. For your quick response& efficient answers. As for the size*10 thing, it was a random idea, I came up with, to deal with one of the Segmentation Fault errors. Never thought the size+1 option. I've learned a lot from you all. Will come with a new question soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I have a harde time understanding the logic behind the "temp" variable.

Comment: Got the logic behind "temp". Not bad, but the variable name isn't helpfull at all, and since there are no commentary and given how temp is used in your code, it's hard to understand the logic. "temp" is the "endOfCurrentString", in order to do a quick concatenation. The OP just failed to used it correctly

Comment: Also, why did you malloc ten time the required space ? Why not just "temp = malloc(size + 1);" ?

Comment: Uhhhh, fgets will read up to size - 1 or if he found a newline ('\n'), or obviously EOF. I think you mean fread ?

Comment: regarding: `char* concat(char* dest, char* src)
     {
      //function to concatenate src to dest
      while(*dest) dest++;
      while(*dest++ = *src++);
      return --dest;
     }`   This does NOT perform a concat operation.  Suggest using function: `strcat()`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` ) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `ftell()`, always check (!=-1) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fseek()`, always check (!=-1) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding the call to the sub function: `fsize()`, the file is already open, so better to just pass the opened file pointer `fip` and add a statement at the end of `fsize()` similar to: `fseek( fip, 0L, SEEK_SET );  (along with checking for an error indication returned from that function call.

Comment: the parameter passed to `malloc()` should be of type `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: regarding: `temp = malloc(size*10);`  what if the input file was (say) 2 gig in size.  Then the value passed to `malloc()` would (try to be) 20 gig, but a 'int` (size) has a max positive value of 2gig, so an overflow would occur in a signed number.  That would result in undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `temp = malloc(size*10);
      text = temp;` and `temp = concat(text,read);i++;`  if the call to `malloc()` fails, then `text` contains NULL and the call to `concat()` will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: on the first call to `concat()` the first byte of the memory pointed to by `text` could be anything.  I.E. it only has 1/256 chance of being 0x00.  The result of the call to `concat()` is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  Strongly suggest that each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `if(fip==NULL)
      {
        temp = strdup("ERROR : File doesn't exist! Please try again!\n");
        return temp;
      }`  This should be immediately after the call to `fopen()` AND the first statement in the `if()` block should be: `perror( "fopen failed" );` so the reason the system thinks the failure occurred is output to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(read, 1024, fip) != NULL)
      {
        temp = concat(text,read);i++;
      }`  why set `temp`?  that variable is not used in the next pass through the loop (i.E. in the call to `concat` so it lost

Comment: the variable `temp` can be easily replaced with `text` throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `prt = malloc(256);
      printf("\nEnter the name of the file : \t");
      scanf("%255s",prt);`  if the call to `malloc()` fails, then the call to `scanf()` will be writing to address 0, This will result in a seg fault event.  If the call to `scanf()` fails (returned value not == 1) then all following references to 'prt' will be trying to use trash.  Always check the returned values from calls to C library functions

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include<ctype.h>`

Comment: the `read` is a well known C library function.  The user code should not be redefining it as a local variable.

Comment: @JohnH,  the function: `fgets()` does not perform as you indicated in your comments.  Perhaps you are thinking of `fread()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use "text" as a string but failed to do it.
A "string" in C is a char array terminated by '\0'.

If you use any string related function, you have to unsure that you give string !
So after you allocated "text" (througth "temp"), "text" is not yet a string since it doesn't contain '\0'.
Since it's an "empty" string at the beginning, you have to initialize by doing

```
text[0] = '\0';
```

Now, why your file is printed twice ? Dunno, but I have to bet on an UB since your string wasn't properly initialized.